# Add missing ZERO on HH:MM:SS in SQL column

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime

This is the format I need from a T-SQL Column **HH:MM:SS**

Example:

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),108)` -- *11:06:03*

I have these values: **(*Select duration from MyTable*)**

> 2:13:00
>
> 11:02
>
> 0:43

That needs to be this:

> 02:13:00
>
> 00:11:02
>
> 00:00:43

How can this be done in T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187928.aspx), then cast 
transformation. The peculiarity here is hidden in omitted hours string, while sql server assumes seconds omitted.

```
Select 
   CONVERT(time(0), 
      case when len(duration) > 5 then duration else '00:' + duration end, 108)
from MyTable
```

Examples:

```
SELECT CONVERT(time(0), 
  case when len('2:13:00') > 5 then '2:13:00' else '00:' + '2:13:00' end ,108)
SELECT CONVERT(time(0), 
  case when len('11:02') > 5 then '11:02' else '00:' + '11:02' end ,108)
SELECT CONVERT(time(0), 
   case when len('0:43') > 5 then '0:43' else '00:' + '0:43' end ,108)
--------------
02:13:00
00:11:02
00:00:43
```

- Update1: optimized the answer to time(0) due @Mikael Eriksson tip
- Update2: modified solution concerning example2 requirement

Comment: Perfect, thanks for update! That is what I wanted! Not sure why 2 people gave me a down vote for this question!

Comment: Another problem....what if I need HH values are more than 23? Like what about 285:28:02? That is a total of 285 hours, 28 minutes and 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me at the end.....

```
SELECT  RIGHT('000' + CASE WHEN LEN(Duration) > 5
                       THEN LEFT(duration, CHARINDEX(':', duration) - 1)
                       ELSE 0 -- Hours
                  END, 3) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00'  + CASE WHEN LEN(Duration) > 5
                       THEN SUBSTRING(duration
                                    ,CHARINDEX(':',duration) + 1
                                    ,CHARINDEX(':',duration
                                        ,CHARINDEX(':',duration) + 1) - 1- CHARINDEX(':',duration))
                            ELSE LEFT(duration,CHARINDEX(':',duration) - 1)END, 2) + ':' + -- Minutes
        RIGHT('00'+ RIGHT(duration, 2), 2) -- Seconds
        NewDuration

   FROM    MyTable
```